# Bulkify a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, after-trigger, bulkification

I have written a trigger on Tenant_Details__c object which has a lookup relationship to Room_Details__c object. Every time a new record is inserted, I want to update a field in Room_Details__c and also a field in all the Tenants present in that Room in which that tenant has been added. My trigger is working when I insert an individual record, but when I try to enter multiple records simultaneously, then it throws an error. The reason is that it is not bulkified. Con someone please help me bulkify this code.

```
trigger addTenant on Tenant_Details__c (after insert) 
{   
    List<Tenant_Details__c> tenantDetailList = [select Contribution__c, Stays_in__c from Tenant_Details__c where id in :Trigger.new];

    List<Tenant_Details__c> tenantDetailListToUpdate = new List<Tenant_Details__c>();
    List<Room_Details__c> roomDetailListToUpdate = new List<Room_Details__c>();

    for(Tenant_Details__c tenant : tenantDetailList)
    {
        Room_Details__c rooms=[select Rent__c, Sharing_Capacity__c, Present_Tenant_Count__c from Room_Details__c where id = :tenant.Stays_in__c];

        System.debug('Trigger.isInsert');
        System.debug('Previous tenant count:'+rooms.Present_Tenant_Count__c);
        if(rooms.Present_Tenant_Count__c<rooms.Sharing_Capacity__c)
        {
            rooms.Present_Tenant_Count__c=rooms.Present_Tenant_Count__c+1;//3. updating tenant count 

        }
        else
        {
            System.debug('Maximum tenant count reached');
            Trigger.oldMap.get(rooms.Id).addError('Cannot add tenants to this room.');//4. add error on max capacity
        }

        //5. increase rent of each tenant
        System.debug('New tenant count: '+rooms.Present_Tenant_Count__c);
        Double contri = rooms.Rent__c/rooms.Present_Tenant_Count__c;
        tenant.Contribution__c=contri;     

        for(Tenant_Details__c allTenants:[select Contribution__c from Tenant_Details__c where Stays_in__c=:tenant.Stays_in__c])
        {
            allTenants.Contribution__c=contri;
            tenantDetailListToUpdate.add(allTenants);
        }

        roomDetailListToUpdate.add(rooms);
    }
    update roomDetailListToUpdate;
    update tenantDetailListToUpdate;

}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond bulkification, I think you are likely to have an issue with this line:

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(rooms.Id).addError('Cannot add tenants to this room.');
```

Because it looks to me like you are trying to retrieve a Tenant_details__c record using the id from a room_detail__c record.

Regarding bulkification, your updates are outside of the for loop, you could also pull out the SOQL query -

You can make a list with all of the ids you are going to query on, make a `WHERE id IN :list` query, put that into a map with the list id as the key, then within your for loop retrieve the relevant record from the map rather than from a SOQL query.

```
List<Id> tenantRoomIds = new List<Id>();
for(Tenant_Details__c tenant : tenantDetailList){
     tenantRoomIds.add(tenant.Stays_in__c);
} 
Map<Id, Room_Details__c> Room_Details__c rooms= Map<ID, Room_Details__c>([select
 Rent__c, Sharing_Capacity__c, Present_Tenant_Count__c from Room_Details__c where
 id IN :tenantRoomIds]);

for(Tenant_Details__c tenant : tenantDetailList){
    room_detail__c room = rooms.get(tenant.Stays_in__c);
...
```

You've also got a nested SOQL for loop :

```
        for(Tenant_Details__c allTenants:[select Contribution__c from Tenant_Details__c where Stays_in__c=:tenant.Stays_in__c])
```

I think you'd be better off retrieving the child objects from your query on room, and then looping through those child objects so rooms query becomes -

```
Map<Id, Room_Details__c> Room_Details__c rooms= Map<ID, Room_Details__c>(
[select Rent__c, Sharing_Capacity__c, Present_Tenant_Count__c, 
(SELECT contribution__c FROM Tenant_Details__r) 
from Room_Details__c where
 id IN :tenantRoomIds])
```

Then you can replace your SOQL for loop with:

```
for(tenant_details__c tenant :room.tenant_details__r){
    tenant.Contribution__c=contri;
    tenantDetailListToUpdate.add(tenant);

}
```

You might also have an issue with updating tenants within a tenant trigger - could get into infinite loop, so watch out for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
It worked perfectly.